# How to keep track of a class's objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm new to C and Objective-C, and would like to implement a class method to return a NSDictionary of all objects meeting a certain criteria, such as all the starred articles in this example:

### Article.h:

```
@interface Article : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
    BOOL starred;
}
...
+ (NSMutableDictionary*) starredArticles;
@end
```

How would I approach this? Static global NSMutableArray inside the Article.m file, then insert/delete in the constructor and destructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't the way to go--there must be some object containing the articles in your application. *That's* the object that should return the starred articles--this class method might seem a good idea now, but it's very inflexible.

So, say you have an object storing all your articles in an `NSMutableArray`. Then you could use a predicate (see [the Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/)) to find only the starred articles and return the desired dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I would leave code which is specific to a particular instance of a class within that class, and code which operates on a collection of such objects in the controller which manages the collection.

In other words, make your class and compose it of instance variables as you see fit for you need, synthesize some accessor methods, write any other methods you may require relevant to the ivars. Then in your controller in which you actually use/reference these objects, you must have some form of collection (NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary, NSMutableSet) to hold them in. That is the controller in which you should implement your method to count the number of starred articles.

You will probably only ever use that method to count the number of starred articles in the controller where you are "controlling" the articles (where you have the NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableSet of Articles), so it makes sense to implement it there. You can always implement your own collection class which has a collection ivar holding your articles; and then you can implement your starredArticles method there along with e.g. addArticle, article, replaceArticle, deleteArticle.

The method you suggested leads to very confusing code, and decreases code reusability, I would personally try and avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to read up on how to use controller classes.

Comment: Read a little about the MVC (model-view-controller) paradigm. If you adopt it, it will save you a lot of time in the future ;). Have a look on iTunes U for cs193p, it's a iOS dev course taught at Stanford. They have a good lecture on MVC.

Comment: +1, however, don't name your getters "getArticle"; it's Cocoa-stylish to name them just plain "article".